# Dual of a point which is in the convex cone of a set, contains the dual cone of that set

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, duality-theorems, convex-geometry

Let $\Lambda\subseteq R^n$ contains $m$ elements, where $\lambda_i$ is the $ith$ element, and $co(\Lambda)$ is the smallest convex cone contains $\Lambda$. Also, consider any point $u\in R^n$. Now, I would like to prove that $u\in co(\Lambda)$ if and only if $\Lambda^* \subseteq \{u\}^*$.

I think it is a well-known theorem, but I don't know its name; and so, I can't find it in the literature. The proof from left to right is pretty straightforward and I can do, but I can't figure out how to obtain the left side from the right.

Comment: I think the argument is that $A\subset B\implies B^*\subset A^*$, and that $A^{**}=A$ when $A$ is a convex cone.

Comment: @sandwich: It sounds plausible, but I have no idea about the proof of this statement: if $A\subset B$ then $B^* \subset A^*$ .

Comment: @Mojtaba: This is rather easy: $A^* = \{x \in \mathbb R^n : a^\top \, x \le 0 \forall a \in A\} = \bigcap_{a \in A} \{x \in \mathbb R^n : a^\top \, x \le 0 \} \supset \bigcap_{b \in B } \{x \in \mathbb R^n : b^\top \, x \le 0\} = B^*$.